# tree_hierachral data in GUI design, ----for RGtk2, a package in R used GTK

Tags: r, user-interface, treeview, gtk, signals

In RGtk2, we can create a treeview for a hierachral data, and there are several signals associated with this representation , We want to to "click" the item then it shows something to our user, but all signals are either "double clicked" or are for "cursor move" type, there is no signals associated for "single click". So is there anyway that we just do a single click the item then it emits signal to show something ?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ideas:

Maybe this: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeView.html#GtkTreeView-row-activated

Or you can connect a "changed" event to the selection model.

Or the "button-press-event" of GtkWidget, but then you would likely have to fish out the item that was clicked on.

Comment: can you tell me how to correct the "activate-on-single-click" property to be TRUE

Comment: Got me there. I wasn't careful and showed you something that appeared in gtk3. I would think then the second option is the preferred way to do this.

Comment: OK, my code is "view<-gtkTreeView(model) , selection <- view$getSelection(), gSingalConnect(selection, signal='changed',f=function(){...})", in {...},I want to get the path of my selection and then got like path[1],path[2], to retrieve the levels of my path to do somthing later, but it seems that I can't go from my selection to the corresponding path ?

Comment: does getSelectedRows get what you want? It isn't ideal, as you don't have the just selected/deselected item passed through the change signal.